# Compare keys of 2 different JSON Objects and return the key along with its value that does not match

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script

I've two json objects. I have also used json.stringfy on them.

Json1 and json2 has certain keys.
Few keys are similar in both the objects while others are different.
I don't care if the values are different in both the objects.
I wanted to return the unmatched keys of Json1 along with its values after checking if the key exists in json2.

Ex:

```
Json1:{
"A":2,
"B": "jrrj"  }

Json2 : {
"A" : 6,
"C" : "jrdj" 
}
```

Output Expected:

```
Result: {
"B" : "jrrj" 
}
```

I searched for the solution a lot on the SO but couldn't find a suitable one that does exactly the same and I'm unable to figure out one.

Please help me out.

P.S - right now I'm on js version ES5.

Comment: Object entries, filter, Object keys, includes

Comment: I did not get what you're trying to tell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that's *flat* object and keys that are missing from second object, you may:

- Extract `Object.keys()` of the first object
- Use `Array.prototype.reduce()` to traverse the latter and turn that into an object having its properties set to unique properties of the first object

Following is a quick demo:

```js
const o1 ={"A":2,"B":"jrrj"},
      o2 ={"A":6,"C":"jrdj"},

      diff = Object
              .keys(o1)
              .reduce((r,key) => 
                (!(key in o2) && (r[key] = o1[key]), r), {})
 
      
console.log(diff)
```

---

### ES5-compatible version

```js
const o1 ={"A":2,"B":"jrrj"},
      o2 ={"A":6,"C":"jrdj"},

      diff = Object
        .keys(o1)
        .reduce(function(r, key){
          if(!(key in o2)) r[key] = o1[key]
          return r
        }, {})
      
console.log(diff)
```

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the answer but => operator are not supported in the current version of apps script that mostly uses JS.

Comment: @Diwas : that is something, you should've mentioned in your original post, so, the problem is even bigger - neither `Object.assign()`, nor spread syntax will be supported as well

Comment: My bad. I've added it  now to the post. Apologies.

Comment: @Diwas : check out ES5 compatible version [over here](https://codepen.io/ygorbunkov/pen/eYJaLQj?editors=0012)

Comment: @Diwas That's not true. Apps script is v8 compatible.

Comment: FWIW, The reduce version looks much cleaner than the roundabout version of mapping keys to empty objects and then  spread and copying them  with assign

Comment: @TheMaster : `.reduce()` is often hard to comprehend to people asking fairly simple questions (`Object.assign()`-way is not that obvious either, I must admit, though), so I avoided that on purpose. However, as I did some benchmarks I had to admit that `.reduce()`-based way is noticeable faster as well. So, changed my answer. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

```
const object_1 = {"A":2,"B":"jrrj"};
const object_2 = {"A":6,"C":"jrdj"};

var new_obj = {};

Object.keys(object_1).map(
  function(obj_1_key){
    if(!object_2[obj_1_key]){
        new_obj[obj_1_key] = object_1[obj_1_key];
    }
  }
)

console.log(new_obj);
```

Comment: Using `.map()` for this case is somewhat confusing as it is normally expected to return an array. For simple looping over `Object.keys()` you'd be much better off with `Array.prototype.forEach()`